# Avoid using Object.values

Tags: javascript

df is an array of objects

I want to simplify this code, maybe the usage of `Object.values` could be redundant if I use another thing than `map`

```
Object.values(df.map(o => o.prop))
```

This piece of code returns an array of props.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `df` is a sparse array, the `Object.values` is totally redundant indeed.

```
df.map(o => o.prop)
```

already returns the same value as

```
Object.values(df.map(o => o.prop))
```